# MongoDB: How to delete all comments of a deleted post?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm following Thinkster's MEAN stack tutorial (https://thinkster.io/tutorials/mean-stack), which doesn't tell how delete operations should be implemented.

I currently have the following schemas:

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 140},
  link: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 300},
  comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});

var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  body: {type: String, maxlength: 200, minlength: 1},
  post: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }
});
```

I have an Angular factory for CRUD operations. I currently delete posts with the following factory method:

```
o.deletePost = function(id) {
  return $http.delete('/posts/' + id, null, {}
  }).success(function(res){
    $window.location.href = '/#/home'; 
    return res.data;
  });
};
```

And my router for delete looks like this:

```
// DELETE a post
router.delete('/posts/:post', function(req, res, next) {  
    Post.remove({_id: req.params.post}, function(err, post) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted' });        
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, when I delete a post like this any related comments are left somewhere in the database. So, my question is **how could I delete all comments related to a post while deleting that post?**

I've tried to Google for the answer and it seems I should somehow use MongoDB's middleware. I've tried:

```
// Remove Post
module.exports.removePost = function(id, callback){   
    Post.findById(id, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {}

        doc.remove(callback);
    })
}

//Remove comments related to post
PostSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {

    this.model('Comment').remove({ post: this._id }, next);
});
```

But this doesn't do anything, since I don't know how to call it from my CRUD factory. Don't know if it would be right even if I did. So, any help would be welcome. :)

Comment: Do you not even get your 'Successfully deleted' message? Have you tried testing it with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)?

Comment: @gh0st I updated my question with the router information.

Comment: @gh0st I get the message and I can delete posts without a problem. The problem is that when I delete a post all related comments are left "floating" in the database. I'd like to get rid of them when the associated post is deleted.

Comment: After your `Post.remove();` make a call to `Comments.remove();` passing in the id of the post it's associated with.

Comment: @gh0st Thanks, works like a charm! :) But I'm left wondering if this is the preferred method for deleting references instead of creating a custom schema method for delete. Any ideas?

Comment: @catfood did you try using your `removePost` function in the `delete` route? That should trigger the middleware automatically. The code in the delete route above won't trigger the middleware, because it's calling `remove()` on the model instead of the document

Comment: @theholla Originally no, but I've tried it after your response; didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose middleware will be automatically triggered when you call `remove()` on a Mongoose document. The code in the `delete` route above won't trigger the middleware, because it's calling `remove()` on the model instead of the document (conversation about this [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1241)).

I think you have all the pieces, you just need to move them around. Keep the logic from your `removePost()` function and `pre('remove')` middleware, and incorporate the logic into your delete route:

```
// DELETE a post
router.delete('/posts/:post', function(req, res, next) {
    Post.findById(id, function (err, post) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        post.remove(function (err, doc) {
            if (err) res.send(err);
            res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted' });
        });
    })
});
```

I approach "deleting" differently though. Rather than actually deleting the document, I add a `deleted` field to my schemas and update that field to `true` on delete. In some cases it makes sense to actually delete the document, but this is something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't work. I only get an internal server error 500, if I replace my current router.delete with that.

Comment: It seems I can't reach the removePost method at all with router.delete. The method (removePost) is currently in the same file as my PostSchema. Is this the correct location for it?

Comment: Oh okay, you will have to import the function if you want to use it in another file. But instead of all that, you could just take the guts of the `removePost()` function and call that instead, from the `delete` route.

Comment: How (and where) would I import it? And if I were to go with your suggestion of including the contents of `removePost()` in my `delete` route where should I put my `PostSchema.pre` hook? In the same file where my `PostSchema` is?

Comment: Yes, you can add the pre hook to the same file as your schema definition. Check out the Node [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_object) for info about requiring modules

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's wondering what exactly solved my question, here are two different solutions:

The first one that works, suggested by gh0st, was changing my router for delete as follows:

```
// DELETE a post
router.delete('/posts/:post', function(req, res, next) {  
    Post.remove({_id: req.params.post}, function(err, post) {
        if (err) {res.send(err);}

        Comment.remove({post: req.params.post}, function(err, post) {
        if (err) {res.send(err);}                
        }); 

        res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted' });        
    });    
});
```

The second one that also works, suggested by the holla, was changing my router for delete as follows:

```
// DELETE a post
router.delete('/posts/:post', function(req, res, next) {

    Post.findOne({ _id: req.params.post}, function (err, post) {
      if (err) {res.send(err);}

      post.remove(function (err) {
        if (err) {res.send(err);}

        res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted' });
      });
    });
});
```

And then adding a pre hook to my schema file:

```
// Remove comments related to a post
PostSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
    this.model('Comment').remove({ post: this._id }, next);
});
```